# JavaFX Node.snapshot() freezes thread when called from worker thread, ideas?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2

I need to write a `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` to a `javafx.scene.image.WritableImage`. I am aware that the snapshot() method in `javafx.scene.Node` will perform this, and it works great when I'm on the JavaFX Application thread.

But I need to perform this write from a worker thread that utilizes the `javafx.concurrent` package. So I have a `javafx.concurrent.Task<V>` that attempts to call the `snapshot()` method from within its `call()` method. When attempting to do this, the thread freezes when it calls `snapshot()`.

So my question is am I allowed to call`snapshot()` from a worker thread from that utilizes the `javafx.concurrent` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Platfrom#runLater()` which was introduced exactly for this kind of tasks:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myNode.snapshot(...)
    }
}
```

You can run this code from the any thread, but `snapshot()` method would be called on FX App Thread as required.